# Permanently storing records in an array python. Without writing to a file?

Tags: python-3.x, data-storage

For my Coursework i am creating a password manager.
Using Tkinter i have created a basic UI for a login and SignUp page. I want to store the users SignUp Details without writing to a file in order to maintain security. Everything is locally stored.

Is there a way of storing records in an array without writing to a file. I want the data to be persistent so that it is still there even if the program is shut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data needs to be stored even if the program is shut down, then no, there is no way to store it without writing to a file. (Any method of data storage between boots ends up using a file.)

For storing data in a file, there are plenty of options to choose from. If your data is text-based, you could simply store the array as a file where each array item is one line. If you have more complex data than that, a quick-and-easy solution is [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html); a more robust solution is [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html). If writing to a single file doesn't appeal to you, then you can use a standard database solution like MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I guess i will have to write to a file, maybe try to encrypt the test within that file aswell.

Comment: @MuratSaglam If this answer solved your problem, I recommend you mark it as accepted so that others who have your problem will see that this helped you.

Comment: @MuratSaglam. Take a look at soemthing like KeePass. It's much more complicated than what you are trying to do, but it will give you ideas.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Will do.